# Display form data on another webpage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, input

Why is the name not being displayed in the new window? This is a simple HTML5 and JavaScript based doubt. Everything is getting displayed except the input entered in the text box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myname = document.myform.name.value;
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>Name : </p>" + myname);
}
</script>
<p>Click the button to open a new window called "MsgWindow" with some text.
</p>
<form method="POST" name="myform">
<input type="text" name="name">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by saying the name isn't displayed? Here's a pen of your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMrBaK

The name is displayed, it's just that the window is small and so you have to scroll down to see.

Comment: LOL!!! That's so ridiculous of me. Thanks a lot, bro! You made my day... !!